# Can't set spell check language (Google chrome)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome

I tried to change the language of my input in order to change spell-check from English to french but still not wokring.

```
<textarea className="input"   lang="fr" spellCheck="true"/>
```

How can i change the spellcheck.

Answer (score 1):

The `spellcheck` tag only informs the browser that it should enable the spellchecking in that field.

If the user doesn't have the dictionary for the language that you're setting (in this case, French), it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

### The "generic" language might not work for spell checking

I recently had a similar problem: I had English as one of my preferred languages, but chrome wouldn't allow me to pick English to spell check. The solution for me was to remove the *generic* English from my preferred languages in the language settings, and add a *national* English, so for example "English (United States)". Then it would let me pick English to spell check my text.